# Save image to a specific folder using Camera X ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder below android 29

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I am trying to implement Camera X app. The problem i am facing right now is i am not able to figure out how to save image below to a specific folder using `ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder`

My current code is below. Do i need to adopt some other way? Or i can also do in this way?

```
    private void capturePhoto() {

        showProgress(true);

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, makeImageName(currentTime));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {

            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, currentTime);

            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + FOLDER_IMAGES);


        } else {

            // Todo ( Something equivalent to RELATIVE_PATH)

        }

        ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions options = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues).build();


        imageCapture.takePicture(options,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults results) {

                        ToastUtility.successToast(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Photo Capture Successfully");

                        showProgress(false);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {

                        ToastUtility.errorToast(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Photo Couldn't Capture");

                        showProgress(false);

                    }
                });

    }
```

**Update # 1**

Solved this by following code

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {

            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, currentTime);

            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + FOLDER_IMAGES);


        } else {

            createFolderIfNotExist();

            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + FOLDER_IMAGES + "/" + imageDisplayName;

            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, path);

        }
```

```
    private void createFolderIfNotExist() {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + FOLDER_IMAGES);


        if (!file.exists()) {

            if (!file.mkdir()) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Folder Create -> Failure");

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "Folder Create -> Success");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Below Android 29 you use .DATA column for full path (inclusive or without filename i forgot try both).

Comment: `Or i can also do in this way?` Well you will have tried that already and could have told us where the files land now if it works.

Comment: @blackapps what i was meant by this. Can i do something in this scenario or i have to do in different way? For api >= 29 it goes inside the Pictures/BeautyCam and in case of api < 29 it goes in Pictures/

Comment: If you are satisfied with that... if it works .. then what is the problem .. what is the question? If you want them to land in FOLDER_IMAGES then use that in full path for .DATA column.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: ```contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + FOLDER_IMAGES);``` This make them to go in specific folder. How to do this with DATA column?

Comment: Yes i know. But ???  If you can put a relative path in .RELATIVE_PATH then why would you not be able to put a full path in .DATA? You could at least try. If it does not work we will comment.

Comment: ```contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, fullPath);``` you mean like that?

Comment: Exactly. But.. i cannot see the path you used..

Comment: Okay can you tell how to build that path?

Comment: Yes. But before i do i would like you to tell fulll path of Pictures folder.

Comment: Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Comment: No that is only the folder name. You used that as RELATIVE_PATH. That is only "Pictures". Log it to see..